# removing field in form dynamically sencha 2

Tags: extjs4, extjs, sencha-touch-2

i am using sencha touch 2.0 and want to create a button '+' and '-',to add and remove a field dynamically,i have figured out the add part using

> this.getForm().insert({...});

but remove part does not hide the field.

> this.getForm().remove('...');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set an id for your field and then try

`this.getForm().remove('your_field_id_here')`

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks ,but i have already done that,but the field is still visible,do i have to hide it somehow

Comment: hmm it seems weird... ok, last thing, try using `Ext.getCmp("your_field_id").hide()`, 100% assured to work

Comment: i used this.getAddformButton().hide(); and it worked !!,thanks alot for your help